# OS X 10.6 Apply ipfw rules at startup

Tags: mac-osx, firewall, startup

I have a couple of firewall rules I would to like to apply at startup. I have followed the instructions from http://images.apple.com/support/security/guides/docs/SnowLeopard_Security_Config_v10.6.pdf On page 192.

However, the rules do not get applied at startup.

I am running 10.6.8 NON Server Edition.

I can however run: (Which applies the rules correctly)

```
sudo ipfw /etc/ipfw.conf
```

Which results in:

```
00100 fwd 127.0.0.1,8080 tcp from any to any dst-port 80 in
00200 fwd 127.0.0.1,8443 tcp from any to any dst-port 443 in
65535 allow ip from any to any
```

Here is my /etc/ipfw.conf

```
# To get real 80 and 443 while loading vagrant vbox
add fwd localhost,8080 tcp from any to any 80 in
add fwd localhost,8443 tcp from any to any 443 in
```

Here is my /Library/LaunchDaemons/ipfw.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
        <string>ipfw</string>
    <key>Program</key>
        <string>/sbin/ipfw</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/sbin/ipfw</string>
            <string>/etc/ipfw.conf</string>
        </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true />
</dict>
</plist>
```

The permissions of all the files seem to be appropriate:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  wheel  151 Oct 11 14:11 /etc/ipfw.conf
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  wheel  438 Oct 11 14:09 /Library/LaunchDaemons/ipfw.plist
```

Any thoughts or ideas on what could be wrong would be very helpful!

Comment: Does Console.app or any of the logs in /var/log have errors related to it from startup?  Does running it manually via launchctl show anything helpful?  sudo launchctl load /Library...ipfw.plist

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to polynomial for having me test via launchctl. The result was:

```
launchctl: Dubious ownership on file (skipping)...
```

I changed the permissions as follows:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  438 Oct 11 14:09 /Library/LaunchDaemons/ipfw.plist
```

Then everything worked great. Also found if the `@` is present (Extended attribute flag) this can also cause the same problem.